# Can't run Laravel Envoy with exec (works in command line but doesn't with Artisan::call)

Tags: php, laravel, exec, shell-exec, laravel-envoy

I have an envoy script which I am triggering within Laravel Command.

`php artisan proxy:update`

```
public function handle() {
   exec("envoy run update");
}
```

If I run this on command line as `php artisan proxy:update`, it works.

However if I run this inside my Laravel app as `Artisan::call('proxy:configure');` it doesn't work.

---

In console `whoami` = vagrant; likewise in my command `exec('whoami')` is also vagrant.

---

If I change it to

```
$out =  shell_exec('envoy run update');
dd($out);
```

In command-line it shows the output, but with `Artisan::call()`, it returns empty string.

---

What might be the issue for being able to use `exec()` with artisan command?

---

Comment: As far as I understand, php-fpm was blocking it. I tried using [Symfony's Process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) instead of exec() and I was getting "terminated". Then I moved `Artisan::call()` to `Artisan::queue()` and it worked. I'd be happy to know if anyone has any other explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, php-fpm was blocking it. I tried using Symfony's Process instead of `exec()` and I was getting "terminated". Then I moved `Artisan::call()` to `Artisan::queue()` and it worked. I'd be happy to know if anyone has any other explanations.

Update:
I created a queue that is run by `deployer` user which has sudo privileges (normally www-data run my queues). Now it works perfectly.